# How can I connect my Retrofit Interceptor with my Glide?

Tags: kotlin, interceptor

I have an Interceptor to send my authToken to the API for the verifying but I need to send the token when I load the image from the API too but I have no clue I already try everything but nothing works. Can I connect my Interceptor with my Glide?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add authorization in header by Glide in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149546/how-to-add-authorization-in-header-by-glide-in-android-studio)

Comment: `RetroFit` and `Glide` has nothing to do with each other . they r two different libraries.

Comment: Where I have to write the code ? In AppGlidemodule ? or before in the Adapter class where I call Glide?

Answer (score 0):

this is my Adapter,

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryItem, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position))
    val currentItem = getItem(position)

    holder.apply {

        token = sessionManager.fetchAuthToken().toString()
        val url=(getItem(position)).image?.url

        val glideUrl = GlideUrl(
            url,
            LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .addHeader( "X-FIREBASE-TOKEN", token)
                .build()
        )

        Glide.with(itemView)
            .load(currentItem.image?.url)
            .into(itemView.post_image)
```

com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Unauthorized, status code: 401)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE